# OR filter for Google Drive Api q objects

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I am trying to use the Google Drive python client to select all filetypes with mimeType audio/mpeg OR audio/flac OR audio/ogg. How can this be done in a single query? 
I have tried:

```
files = drive.files().list().setQ("mimeType='audio/mpeg OR mimeType='audio/flac'").execute()
```

But this request failed to yield the correct result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've lost one single-quote in your query and query is invalid:

```
mimeType='audio/mpeg' OR mimeType='audio/flac'
                    ^
```

But still Google Drive API does not support `or` operator, so you have to perform two queries in order to get desired results:

```
mpegs = drive.files().list().setQ("mimeType='audio/mpeg'").execute()
flacs = drive.files().list().setQ("mimeType='audio/flac'").execute()
```